# ConTeXt: Create a list that shows the next item to the right?

Tags: lists, enumerate, context, columns

How to create a list in ConTeXt that shows the next item to the right in ConTeXt?

```
\starttext
    \startitemize[n]
        \item Here is some text.
        \item Here is some more.
        \item Here is yet more.
        \item Here is yet even more text here.
        \item This text also fits.
        \item Here is an example of what happens when the text is really long it just is on its own filling the whole text width.
        \item This is short.
        \item This is really long and look what happens to the text is stays with the block that it is  provided, as if it were surrounded by an invisible box.
        \item This is anther longer text.
        \item This is short.
        \item This is bad it should not smash text like this too much.
    \stopitemize
\stoptext
```

A normal enumerated list looks like this:

```
1. Here is some text.

2. Here is some more.

3. Here is yet more.
```

If put in columns, it looks like this:

```
1. Here is some    3. Here is yet
   text.              more.

2. Here is some
   more.
```

I need to create a list that displays the list almost as if they were in horizontal columns, rather than vertical columns:

```
1. Here is some text.    2. Here is some more.    3. Here is yet more.

4. Here is yet even more text here.    4. This text also fits.

5. Here is an example of what happens when the text is really long
   it just is on its own filling the whole text width.

6. This is short.    7. This is really long and look what happens to
                        the text is stays with the block that it is
                        provided, as if it were surrounded by an
                        invisible box.

8. This is anther longer text.   9. This is short.  10. This is
                                                        bad it
                                                        should not
                                                        smash text
                                                        like this 
                                                        too much.
```

Is there some way to acheive this affect in ConTeXt? (note: avoiding the issue shown in the example above with item 10 being smashed in)

Comment: It's a bit difficult when lengths are different. You could use `\startitemize[horizontal,three] \stopitemize` for horizontal lists, but they won't break if they are too large.

Answer (score 1):

The closest solution to your question would be to use:

```
\starttext

Some previous sentence before the list

\startitemize[a,horizontal,three]
\startitem first \stopitem
\startitem second \stopitem
\startitem third \stopitem
\startitem fourth \stopitem
\startitem fifth \stopitem
\startitem sixth \stopitem
\stopitemize

And the text continues after the list

\stoptext
```

[image: Output of code execution]

This information was obtained from [here](https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Enumerations).